# Unresolved external symbol __tzname Perforce library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, perforce

I'm trying to compile a project from vs 2005 on 2019. I've fixed all the other errors, but I can't seem to get around this error with a static library from perforce:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __tzname referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DateTime::FmtTz(char *)const " (?FmtTz@DateTime@@QBEXPAD@Z)

Comment: Can you change it to `_tzname`? Or perhaps define `char* (&__tzname)[2] = _tzname;`?

Comment: this call is only contained in the library I'm guessing. I've done a search through all the code and it does not contain _tzname.

Comment: No, but the newer version of VS contains `_tzname` so if you change to that, it may work. If you can't change the code using `__tzname` you could perhaps create it as a reference to `_tzname` like I showed.

Comment: Add oldnames.lib to the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.